# SwipeRefreshLayout animation keeps spinning

Tags: android, android-studio, swiperefreshlayout

Everything is in a fragment.

Layout:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout

    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/contentView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

If I drag it down the list is updated, but the animation keeps spinning. I tried putting the layout in a FrameLayout but it doesn't work. I also tried this

```
 @Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    ...

    if (mSwipeRefreshLayout!=null) {
        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
        mSwipeRefreshLayout.destroyDrawingCache();
        mSwipeRefreshLayout.clearAnimation();
    }
}
```

but no luck so far. Any ideas ?

Comment: you need to tell it to stop refreshing when you update the list, `onPause` is only called once the list is not visible either way.

Comment: @ColinGillespie thank you. By simply adding what I have onPause inside onRefresh solved the problem.